# TypeScript project organization, compile into a single JS file?

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript

Recently I started working with TypeScript, using WebStorm IDE. Coming from a strong AS3 background I found TS a really good way to write JS, most of the concepts feel really familiar and convenient, but, when it comes to splitting classes,modules into separate files things starting to get really confusing. All this things with watching for scripts order feels really wrong. AMD is also not the best way in my opinion. The way I want it to work is to have one compiled minified JS file with all of my modules inside. Is this one possible to achieve?

Comment: When you write a question, you don't need to provide a background story about why you like the language or how long you've been working with it. Just focus on your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want to use gulp or grunt. I suggest gulp, but that's a personal preference. You can use this to inject your scripts in a particular order based on your file naming convention.

Comment: Should I use it in conjunction with smth. like AMD or it's not required?

Comment: @AndrewBogdanov depends on the project. If you're on Node.js, you should use `commonjs`. If you're using [`require`](http://requirejs.org/) to load modules, set `amd`. In your case you'll be okay with internal modules, getting one concatenated file (using compiler `out` switch or `gulp-concat`), minifying it and maybe wrapping for use with some module system.